# Change height of pagerTabStrip tabIndicator

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip` in my application.

Here's how I use tabIndicator

```
PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip)
findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#32CD32"));
```

My tabIndicator's height is quite small. How can I set/increase it's height like the one that google play has?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google Play Store uses a custom implementation, rather than the provided `PagerTabStrip`. If you'd like to emulate the look and feel of the Google Play Store, you can use an existing library such as [Pager Sliding TabStrip](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/pager-sliding-tabstrip/) which was designed to model the Google Play Store behavior.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is exactly what I wanted. However, I couldn't find any jar file to import on my project. How can I import this to my project?

Comment: @inankupeli - as Pager Sliding TabStrip support theming, it isn't just a jar file - you have to add the library folder as a Android library project. Instructions for Eclipse can be found at http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Answer (score 1):

its quite simple..

```
mTabStrip.setIndicatorHeight(int indicatorLineHeightPx);
```

Comment: Not sure what version of SDK are you using, but PagerTabStrip does not setIndicatorHeight() method.